# Stored Procedure not executing in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a somewhat simple stored procedure. I first want to verify if there is anything in the table; if there is to TRUNCATE it, if there isn't to populate it with some data. What happens is, it gets execute without any error, but nothing happens to the table. It is as it was before executing it.........empty.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadReportDataCI]
AS
If (Select Count(*) from tbl_TempTableReport)>0 
BEGIN
    Truncate table tbl_TempTableReport
   END 

Begin
INSERT INTO tbl_TempTableReport (userID, VendorID, VendorName, UnitCost,    UnitCount, CostValue)
SELECT  
'1234',    
VendorID,
VendorName,
InvValue,
BegInvOnHand,
BegCurrentValue
From vVendorsAndInvONHand
END
```

If I highlight starting at INSERT until the END, the data gets populated in the table, but otherwise it doesn't work. Shed some light anyone?

Comment: If you want to check for existence of rows you should use exists instead of count. However, since a truncate is so fast why both even checking? Just truncate it. As a side note, you should avoid the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Naming user defined procedure with `sp_` is bad practice.

Comment: Try to move your second begin statement before if, see my answer

Comment: Is this really your exact procedure, or have you simplified it?

Comment: The start of it, I need to add more stuff to it.

Comment: @SeanLange In my experience EXISTS is only faster for simple operations. This is clearly one of those cases :-) But I've had not that complex cases where a COUNT was whole seconds faster than EXISTS - it's worth testing if a sproc is running slowly.

Comment: @eftpotrm IF properly indexed COUNT can perform as well as EXISTS but otherwise in checking for rows it simply isn't going to be faster. Here is one of thousands of articles on the topic. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange Agree it absolutely *shouldn't* be faster, but practical experience of tuning applications suggests it sometimes is, and by very large margins. Always start with EXISTS but keep it in mind and don't dismiss COUNT as a possible performance booster would be my experience.

Comment: @eftpotrm there is truly only one absolute with regards to sql server....there are no absolutes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to checking if there are rows before truncating. It is far faster to just truncate than checking for the existence of rows. If there are no rows it will still run just fine.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadReportDataCI]
AS
    Truncate table tbl_TempTableReport;

    INSERT INTO tbl_TempTableReport 
    (
        userID
        , VendorID
        , VendorName
        , UnitCost
        , UnitCount
        , CostValue
    )
    SELECT  
        '1234'
        , VendorID
        , VendorName
        , InvValue
        , BegInvOnHand
        , BegCurrentValue
    From vVendorsAndInvONHand;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to execute your stored procedure, I have moved your second begin after AS

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_LoadReportDataCI]
AS
Begin
If (Select Count(*) from tbl_TempTableReport)>0 
BEGIN
    Truncate table tbl_TempTableReport
   END 

INSERT INTO tbl_TempTableReport (userID, VendorID, VendorName, UnitCost,    UnitCount, CostValue)
SELECT  
'1234',    
VendorID,
VendorName,
InvValue,
BegInvOnHand,
BegCurrentValue
From vVendorsAndInvONHand
END
```

Comment: it doesn't populate the table. If i highlight from INSERT DOWN, it does.

Comment: Did you move the begin statement as I did?

Comment: @barry17, Did you EXEC the LoadReportDataCI after running the ALTER script?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you didn't execute the Stored Procedure. Did you EXEC the `LoadReportDataCI` after running the `ALTER` script?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.